# How do I continue a for loop when no data is present which causes an index error?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am learning python and I'm guessing something very obvious is at fault here. I have a web scraping program that, I suspect, upon finding an empty data field throws an IndexError: list index out of range. I am trying to get the program to ignore this because there is a lot of missing information in what I am scraping. I don't care if my excel sheet has blank or placeholders in the cells either.

I have tried numerous for, if, and elif statements to plow over the missing data.

I figured going as simple as possible might work though to no avail. Any help is appreciated!

```
import xlsxwriter
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

element_list = []

for page in range(7, 12, 1):

    page_url = "https://website.com" + str(page) + "/?geodir_search=1&stype=gd_professional&s=+&snear&sgeo_lat&sgeo_lon"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get(page_url)
    email = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pg-profile-email")
    name = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pg-profile-name")
    address = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pg-profile-address")
    tel = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pg-profile-tel")

    for i in range(len(email)):
         element_list.append([email[i].text, name[i].text, address[i].text, tel[i].text])
    else:
        continue

with xlsxwriter.Workbook('result008.xlsx') as workbook:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    for row_num, data in enumerate(element_list):
        worksheet.write_row(row_num, 0, data)

driver.close()
```

Comment: To strictly answer the title question: Identify the line that raises the exception and surround it by `try:` and `except IndexError: continue`

Comment: right after posting this I tried:

for i in range (len(email)):
    try:
        ... run your code
    except:
        pass

and it worked but I feel like if one field gets skipped all do. Forgive me for lack of proper lingo.

Comment: Partially solved? I can manually validate that it is getting all the information it can by testing a few pages. I'm worried I am missing something that could do this automatically.